# Hibernate annotations inheritence

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I'm trying to extend the Agent class in order to add a new field.
the Agent class has a field which in sql-server is defined as not-allow nulls but has a default '45' in the db.

The problem is when i try to save and commit some changes, if i don't use the extension then everything is good and the default '45' which were defined at the db is really working and even if i didn't put any value to the field, his value is '45'.

When i use the extension, i really wonder why, the default value '45' is not working and i got data-integrity exception.

This is a code example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a_agent_main")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "agent_no"))
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discriminator", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorOptions(insert=false)
public class Agent extends AbstractRevisionedBusinessIdEntity implements ItemEntityValuesContainer {

    @Column(name = "payment_delay") // this is the column that in the db '45' it's his default value
    private Integer paymentDelay;

    public Integer getPaymentDelay() {
        return this.paymentDelay;
    }

    public void setPaymentDelay(Integer paymentDelay) {
        this.paymentDelay = paymentDelay;
    }
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class AgentExt extends Agent{        
    @Column(name = "z_agent_group_code")
    private Integer agentGroupCode;

    public Integer getAgentGroupCode() {
        return agentGroupCode;
    }

    public void setAgentGroupCode(Integer agentGroupCode) {
        this.agentGroupCode = agentGroupCode;
    }

}
```

The exception i got is:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'payment_delay', table 'dbo.a_agent_main'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Comment: I really wonder why you wouldn't get the same exception with the base entity: a default value is used when an insert statement doesn't specify any value for a column. But Hibernate does specify a value: null. And that's an invalid value. Why don't you make the field an `int` instead of an Integer, and initialize it to 45 by default?

Comment: If i understand you right, if i don't specify any value to the payment_delay column then the default value in the db should work at the insert. But, you are saying that hibernate insert null as a default and that's why the db is ignoring the '45' ? @JBNizet

Comment: Although it is weird that if there is no extension, the value that inserted is '45' even if i don't specify any value to the column, in contradiction to when i use the extension. @JBNizet